# No se ejecuta el catch en la conexión de PHP

Tags: php, mysql

El siguiente codigo es para mostrar mi conexión PDO a MySql:

```
<?php 
    try {
        $conexion=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port:8080;dbname=login_arios', 'root', '');
        echo "Exito";
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error" . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

El problema es que la base de datos se llama login_usuarios no login_arios y aunque esto este mal en la pantalla aparece Exito.

¿Podrían indicarme en que estoy mal?

Comment: ¿Existe la base de datos login_arios?

Comment: @Shaz *El problema es que la base de datos se llama login_usuarios no login_arios y aunque esto este mal en la pantalla aparece Exito.*

Comment: Pero se supone que si me equivoco se tendría que ejecutar el catch

Comment: Un ejemplo claro de ello es la conexión PDO con SQLServer:                        try{
 $servidor='192.168.1.90';
 $base='dbsav300';
 $usuario='sa';
 $password='password';

 $conexion=new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servidor;Database=$base", "$usuario", "$password");
}catch(PDOException $e){
 echo "Error en la conexion:" . $e->getMessage(). "\n";
 exit;
}                                                                                                                  Si me equivoco intencionalmente en la conexión si ejecuta el código del catch

Comment: ¿Qué versión de PHP estás usando?

Comment: Podrías tratar de poner un catch més generico?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está en cómo está la cadena de conexión. En lugar de hacer esto:

```
$conexion=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port:8080;dbname=login_arios', 'root', '');
```

Deberías hacer esto:

```
$conexion=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:8080;dbname=login_arios', 'root', '');
```

Entonces sí que se lanzará una excepción con el siguiente mensaje:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'login_arios'

Este método también lanzará una excepción si el puerto especificado no es válido. Por ejemplo, yo tengo la base de datos MySQL en el puerto por defecto (3306) en lugar de 8080, entonces si intento hacer algo como esto:

```
$conexion=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:8080;dbname=test', 'root', '');
```

Se lanzará una excepción con el siguiente mensaje:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

---

Desafortunadamente, no he encontrado nada en la documentación oficial que diga por qué ocurre este problema exactamente. De hecho, he encontrado mensajes contradictorios a lo que pongo arriba (aunque principalmente en la sección de comentarios, no en la documentación en sí):

- [Un usuario dice que se debe utilizar el parámetro port](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php#87231) como haces;
- [Otro usuario dice que **el parámetro port se ignora si el host es "localhost"**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php#103365) y que se debería utilizar 127.0.0.1 en su lugar (porque usando "localhost" se conecta a través de UNIX sockets en lugar de TCP/IP al especificar una IP);
- También mensajes en los que se recomienda no usar "localhost" sino 127.0.0.1 porque [el host "localhost" falla a partir de PHP7](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php#118288)...

Aunque nada de eso explica por qué no se lanza una excepción al fallar :(

Answer (score 1):

Porque no configuras el "Exception Mode" para realmente validar la conexión:

```
<?php 
    try {
        $conexion=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port:8080;dbname=login_arios', 'root', '');
        $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Exito";
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error" . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

El puerto **`8080`** es (normalmente) para `http`, deberías cambiarlo al puerto **`3306`** de Mysql, cual es configurado por defecto.

Para más información: [Números de puerto (TCP/UDP)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:N%C3%BAmeros_de_puerto)